# Change value in querySet python

Tags: python, database

There is a db, it has double values, which should be unique, to fix that bug there should be script. I tried something like
from fares.models import FareCategory

```
from models import Fc
for x in Fc.objects.all():
    fc = Fc.objects.all().values_list('priority', flat=True)
    if x in fc:
        x.priority = max(fc) +1 
        x.save()
```

But query set has no insert func. What is the best way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Just try this one :

```
fc = Fc.objects.all().values_list('operator_priority', flat=True)
seen_values = set()
new_list = []
for x in fc:
   if x not in seen_values:
       new_list.append(fc)
       seen_values.add(fc)
```

or else try this one also:

```
fc = Fc.objects.all().values_list('operator_priority', flat=True)
new_dict = dict()
for obj in fc:
   if obj not in new_dict:
       new_dict[obj] = obj
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to replace same obj with new maximum one

Comment: then add this line z = max(fc) + 1 and change new_dict[obj] = obj to new_dict[obj] = z